# Выбрать лучший алгоритм

Tags: статический-анализ, алгоритм

Есть 2 алгоритма и набор тестов. Для каждого теста записывается время его исполнения. Можно ли утверждать, что первый алгоритм в среднем лучше? На каком уровне значимости?
Пример:

```
Алг1|  1  |  1  |  1.1  |  1.5 |  5  |  4  
Алг2| 0.8 | 1.3 |  1.7  |  6   | 0.7 |  2
```

Comment: Это вопрос для математиков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Ваш критерий качества - скорость исполнения, то по данным замерам ничего нельзя сказать. Абсолютно.

Нужно оценивать не просто результаты запуска на синтетических тестах, а на реальных боевых условиях. Возможно, что в реальных условиях наиболее частыми будут 4 и 5 наборы. и это будет печально.

Но если уж смотреть на цифры абстрактно, я бы выбрал второй алгоритм, потому что он работает быстрее, а не первый.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы сказать, что один алгоритм лучше или хуже другого нужно опираться на какой-либо критерий качества. Если Вы вибираете в качестве критерия время выполнения, то, да, определенно тот, че среднее время меньше, тот и лучше.   
Но возникает вопрос - а одинаково ли хорошо эти 2 алгоритма справляются с тестами? 
Приведу пример: допустим решается задача классификации(например, обучение по прецедентам). Сравниваются 2 алгоритма. Конечно, здесь можно смотреть на время работы, но это же не главное, главное - процент правильно классификации.

Answer (score 1):

2ой алгоритм быстрее работает:

Вычислим коэффициенты, отношений этих времен (= Время1 / Время2), получим:

```
Алг1 / Алг2|  1,25  |  0,769  |  0,647  |  0,25 |  7,14  |  2
```

Если все эти значения перемножить, то получим число: **2,22** , т.е. Алг1 работает медленнее чем Алг2 примерно в 2,22 раза.

**P.S.**

- на сколько часто будут попадаться 4-ый и 5-ый тест?
- можно сравнивать не среднее значение, а минимальные и максимальные результаты тестов (к примеру меня не устроит алгоритм, если он будет работать медленнее 5,5 секунд и т.д.)